# How to handle DataIntegrityVilolationException while saving a list in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA in a Spring Boot Application, with MYSQL. There I am saving a list of entities with unique constraint over a field. Out of the list of entities, there is one entity that will throw DataIntegrityViolationException due to the unique constraint. I noticed that none of the entities get persisted in that case, even those that does not violate the unique constraint.
What should be the ideal approach in this case so that those entities which do not violate the unique get persisted ?
Of course I can iterate the list and save them one by one. In fact that is what SimpleJpaRepository is doing underneath.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    if (entities == null) {
        return result;
    }

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

My code - Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "name" }, name = "uq_name"))
public class SampleContent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    //getter setters 
}
```

Repository :

```
public interface SampleContentRepository extends JpaRepository<SampleContent, Serializable>{
```

}

JUnit test :

```
@Test
public void testCreate(){
    List<SampleContent> sampleContentList =  new ArrayList<>();
    SampleContent sampleContent1 = new SampleContent();
    sampleContent1.setName("dd");
    SampleContent sampleContent2 = new SampleContent();
    sampleContent2.setName("Roy");
    SampleContent sampleContent3 = new SampleContent();
    sampleContent3.setName("xx");
    sampleContentList.add(sampleContent1);
    sampleContentList.add(sampleContent2);
    sampleContentList.add(sampleContent3);
    try{
        this.sampleContentRepository.save(sampleContentList);
    }catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
        System.err.println("constraint violation!");
    }
}
```

There is an entity with name "Roy" already present in the table. So, the entire transaction fails and @Transactional rolls back.

Comment: that's how it's supposed to work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use next steps:

1. Load existing entities from DB into Set
2. Override `equals` and `hashCode` methods based on `name`
3. call `Set::addAll` you antities (or just add them one by one)
4. save that `Set` to DB

Maybe it's suboptimal because forces you to make `select *` query. But I think it's much more effective then saving entities one by one to DB.

Accotding to [this article](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode) you can use name as your business key, which has lots of benefits.

Comment: That's one way of doing it. But as you pointed out, it will be sub-optimal. I can have a million records in my table. The entities that I'm working with have equals and hashcode overridden, which I'm putting into a Set. I was wondering, if there is any way that I can catch the constraint violation exception and move on with the other entities. I think there is no other way but to iterate through the whole list. Thanks :)

Comment: You always can create query like `select distinct name from table where name in (:your_list_of_names_to_add)`.  Then filter out from collection items with name from results of previous select. Hopefully you won't have to load giant massives of data from DB.